# How do I access a variable in member function #1 in member function #2?

Tags: c++, class, object, friend

I'm starting to work with friends of classes.
Here I have two functions called setMaxSickDays and getMaxSickDays.
I made a variable called maxSickDays in setMaxSickDays that I'd like to access from getMaxSickDays.

```
class timeOff
{
public:
    void setMaxSickDays(numDays &friendlyObject) {  
        int maxSickDays;                         
        friendlyObject.hours = 240;
        maxSickDays = friendlyObject.hours;
    }

    void getMaxSickDays(numDays &friendlyObject) {
        cout << maxSickDays;
    }
};
```

The error: 'maxSickDays' was not declared in this scope

This may seem silly but I'm a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: indent the code first

Comment: Don't edit your question to mark it as solved, accept the in your eyes most helpful answer by clicking the checkmark next to it instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make `maxSickDays` a data member of your class.

```
class timeOff
{
 public:
  void setMaxSickDays(int days);
  int getMaxSickDays();
 private:
  int maxSickDays;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't access another function's local variable, even as `friend`. `friend` is used to granted to access members (i.e. member variables or functions) of the class.

See [friend declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend)

> The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.

Comment: @downvoter Which part is wrong, please let me know it!